# How to override getter/setter of a property in a singleton class Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created singleton class and have a class object(myRecords) as a property inside it. I want to do some implementation handling in this property’s getter/setter.

How can i override the  getter/setter of this property?

Note: The initialization of myRecord is not done inside the singleton.

```
// singleton.h

@interface mySingleton : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@property(nonatomic) myRecords *record;

+(mySingleton *)instance;

@end

// singleton.m
@implementation TRNApplicationContext
+(mySingleton *)instance {

static mySingleton *_instance = nil;

    @synchronized (self) {
        if (_instance == nil) {
            _instance = [[self alloc] init];
        }
    }
    return _instance;
}

-(void) setRecord:(myRecords *)record
{
    self.title = record.name;
    . . .
}

-(myRecords *) record
{
        return self.record;     // Error - EXC_BAD_ACCESS
}

@end

// TestMainViewController.m - Below is Singleton usage

@implementation TestMainViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
 .  .  .
    myRecords *someRecord = [myRecords new];
    someRecord.name = @"test";
    [[mySingleton instance] setRecord:someRecord];
    NSLog(@"value : %@", [[[mySingleton instance] record] name]);
}

@end
```

Comment: do you have the following line in your `setRecord:` method in your singleton class: `_record = record`, it is needed to assign the incoming variable to the instance variable of your singleton object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have stack-overflow error.

You need to change

```
-(myRecords *) record
{
    return self.record;  // call this method again and cause infinite recursion 
}
```

to

```
@synthesize record = _record; // usually put this on the line below @implementation
-(myRecords *) record
{
    return _record;     // return the ivar
}
```

You also need

```
_record = record;
```

inside `setRecord:`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Could you please explain why @synthesize has to be added explicitly. I was under the assumption that synthesize was taken care of as i am using xcode 5.1.

Comment: @user3020200 if you override _both_ getter and setter, you need `@synthesize`. otherwise it won't create the ivar for you because you may not need it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually overriding the getter/setter at all. You are supplying your own implementation, instead of using the implementation supplied by the compiler. You *could* override the getter/setter in a subclass, which would be a very, very strange thing to do.

For implementing singletons, I'd recommend following the usual pattern involving dispatch_once. It's more efficient, it's recognised by everyone, and everyone knows it works.

"myRecords" is a very, very strange name for a class that apparently implements one record. This will be a continuous cause of confusion for anyone reading your code. Similar, "mySingleton" is a very, very strange name for a class. What are you going to to do when you need a different singleton class, call it myOtherSingleton? The name should reflect the purpose of the class, not some implementation detail.

I'd strongly recommend not to use the "new" method but the usual pattern [[myRecords alloc] init]. Using commonly patterns makes your code more readable and instills more confidence in the code. When I see [someClass new] I know that I have to read the surrounding code very carefully.

The "setRecord" setter doesn't actually set the _records instance variable. 
There is no reason to supply a "record" getter. The one supplied by the compiler will do just fine. And as others posted as well, calling the "record" getter from the "record" getter leads to infinite recursion.

The whole problem has of course nothing to do with singletons. You would have the exact same crash for any class with a getter that calls itself recursively. You should also learn how to use the Xcode debugger. The very first thing that you should have done when the crash was detected is to check the call stack, and you would have found that the getter was called by the getter, which was called by the getter, which was called by the getter, and so on forever.

Answer (score 0):

One more simple way is to reduce your code just replace the below two methods as you have already declared property of records variable in .h file. So just declare the synthesize of same variable in .m file it works.

```
    /*  -(void) setRecord:(myRecords *)record
    {
    self.title = record.name;
      . . .
    }

  -(myRecords *) record
    {
    return self.record;     // Error -     
   EXC_BAD_ACCESS
  }*/
```